# Is SQL Server Express good enough for a developer, or should they get Developer edition?

Tags: sql-server

Just wondering if it's worth it for a developer to use SQL Server 2005/2008 Developer Edition instead of the bundled SQL Server Express edition that comes with Visual Studio.  I'm talking about for initial development of a website, where you need to create SQL scripts to generate the tables and things like that.  I know with Express it's easy to add an `.mdf` file to your project and program against that, but wouldn't it be better to install Developer edition and program against a "real" database that would mimic what you're going to be using in production?  That way if you're using VS Professional and can create a "database project" you can include all of your creation scripts and run them in production to recreate the environment.

Comment: You'll never get frustrated having Developer Edition and not use Sql-Express.  You will get frustrated vice versa.  At the same time, try to match what will be using in Production.

Comment: tl;dr Go for the Developer edition.

Answer (score 27):

If you have access to it, you're better off using Developer Edition because it supports more features and larger databases.  For example, if you want to restore a 50gb database from your production server onto your workstation to do testing, you'll need Developer Edition.

Another example is if you're working with Enterprise-only features like partitioning, compression or the Resource Governor.  Those features aren't available in Express, but they are available in Developer Edition.

Comment: I'd like to add though, that Express has the advantage of keeping things small and simple. If you're starting off with an empty database, or a small project, then SQL Server Express would be better, since it's basic. As your project gets larger, you can then go with Developer.

Answer (score 8):

If it is good enough for production then how can it be insufficient in development. And SQL Express is quite capable of handling fair loads (the kind of loads that would have stressed serious hardware just a few years ago).

SQL Server Express does not require licensing but has a smaller set of features.

Developing against full SQL Server (and Developer Edition matches Enterprise Edition) always leaves the chance that you rely on some feature that is not in the production edition.

At the very least all your testing (including unit testing) should happen against the edition to be used in production.

In this question, since a "full" version is being targeted for production then developer edition should be a good match, just be careful of enterprise features if you will deploy against Standard.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I think your development environment should look like as much as you can to your production environment.

**SQL Server Express edition**
has many limitations like size of database, supports only one processor, etc. It is the "lite" version of SQL Server

**SQL Server Developer edition**
is basically Enterprise edition but it cannot be used for production.

Be aware that if the success of your backend database relies on the use of enterprise features for development, and you want the same features on production, this  will require enterprise license.

Comment: Learned this the hard way "back in the day".  (That dev-edition has all the features of enterprise edition) !  I always wished they had dev editions that matched the editions that can be installed on "Production" (Standard, Enterprise, etc).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you are doing. In general, I would say it is fine. If you can get a copy of Developer, I would recommend that route, but a great majority of your work can be done in Express.

Express has basic Reporting, with Advanced Services. If you go beyond the basic Reporting in the product, you will have to move up. YOu also have Service Broker. But, you will not have Analysis Services (no data warehousing) or SSIS (no ETL). If you need either of these features, you have to go to Developer.

You will also not have some of the BI features, as the Express Manager is missing many of the bits in the full SQL Management Studio and BI Developer. If you need these, you will need SQL Server Developer.